# creating .txt file in R

Tags: r, export-to-csv

```
for (i in 3:52){
cat(" ID,NAME,LAT,LONG,ELEVATION
1,25_i_PCP,39.269,-92.127,261.000
2,32_i_PCP,39.241,-92.160,263.000
3,34_i_PCP,39.223,-92.141,264.000
4,38_i_PCP,39.298,-92.083,243.000
5,201_i_PCP,39.228,-92.119,263.000
    ",file="pcpfork_i.txt",sep="\n",append=TRUE)}"
```

I want to create 50 different `.txt` files using the for loop by replacing `i` from 3 to 52.

Comment: Use `file=paste0("pcpfork_",i,".txt")`. Your files are 50 and not 49.

Comment: Thank you i also want to replace the i inside the .txt file for each i

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a couple of options.  First though, a note.  You don't need `append = TRUE` or `sep = "\n"` in your call to `cat()` since there is nothing to append to or separate.  These are all going in separate files.

**Option 1:** In your text, you can replace the `i` with `%d`, call that `tmp`, and then run it through the loop with `sprintf()`.

```
tmp <- "ID,NAME,LAT,LONG,ELEVATION
1,25_%d_PCP,39.269,-92.127,261.000
2,32_%d_PCP,39.241,-92.160,263.000
3,34_%d_PCP,39.223,-92.141,264.000
4,38_%d_PCP,39.298,-92.083,243.000
5,201_%d_PCP,39.228,-92.119,263.000"

for (i in 3:52) {
    cat(
        do.call(sprintf, c(tmp, as.list(rep(i, 5)))), 
        file = sprintf("pcpfork_%d.txt", i)
    )
}
```

**Option 2:** Leave the original text as it is and do the replacement with `gsub()`.

```
tmp <- "ID,NAME,LAT,LONG,ELEVATION
1,25_i_PCP,39.269,-92.127,261.000
2,32_i_PCP,39.241,-92.160,263.000
3,34_i_PCP,39.223,-92.141,264.000
4,38_i_PCP,39.298,-92.083,243.000
5,201_i_PCP,39.228,-92.119,263.000"

for (i in 3:52) {
    cat(
        gsub("_i_", paste0("_", i, "_"), tmp, fixed = TRUE),
        file = sprintf("pcpfork_%d.txt", i)
    )
}
```

Those should get you headed in the right direction.